# Asp.net mvc Actionfilter dynamic view and model loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

I have a mvc project with a home controller

```
 public class HomeController : BaseController
 {
    [MyActionFilter]
    public  ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        var model  = HttpContext.Items["model"] ;
        var viewname = HttpContext.Items["viewname"] as string;
        if (model != null)
            return View(viewname, model);

        model = GetDefaultModel(id);
        return View(model);
    }
```

}

Then i have a action filter

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var id = filterContext.ActionParameters["id"];
        List<IWillDoTheThing> myDoTheThings = LoadAllTheImplementationsOf<IWillDoTheThing>();
        var myObject = myDoTheThings.Where(i => i.IdISupport == id).First().ExecuteTheThing();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Items["viewname"] = myObject.ViewName;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Items["model"] = myObject.Model;

    }
   }
```

Then an interface and a class

```
public interface IWillDoTheThing
{
    string IdISupport { get; set; }
    MyObject ExecuteTheThing();

}

public class MyObject
{
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
    public object Model { get; set; }
}
```

Depending on the id, i load viewname and model (dynamically from other assemblies). So using this method, i can change the home page without any big problem. My only question is, is it a good approach or if there is any better way to do it.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards